# Hiding component vs handling props using componentWillRecieveProps in React

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I having a bootstrap modal component which contains a blog Form where we can either create a new blog or edit an existing blog. When I select a blog to edit then in modal component we call an ajax and then autofill the form data.

My Parent Component looks like this.

```
class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  ...
  editSelectedBlog(blog){
    this.setState({ selectedBlog: blog, modalShown: true, blogEditing: true }, this.showModal)
  }

  showNewBlogModal() {
    this.setState({ modalShown: true, blogEditing: false }, this.showModal)
  }

  showModal() {
    $('#addBlog').modal('show')
  }

  hideModal(updateBlogs = false) {
    this.setState({ modalShown: false, blogEditing: false })
    if (updateBlogs) { // call ajax and fetch updated blogs }
  }

  render() {
    ...
    <Blogs>
      {blogs.map((blog) => {
        return (
          <Blog
            key={shortid.generate()}
            blog={blog}
            onEditItem={this.editSelectedBlog}
          />
        )
      }
      )}
    </Blogs>
    {modalShown &&
      <BlogModal
        postApi={someUrl}
        selectedBlogId={this.state.selectedBlog? this.state.selectedBlog.id : undefined}
        onModalHide={this.hideModal}

      />
    }
    <div role="presentation" onClick={this.showNewBlogModal} > Add new blog
    </div>
  }
}
```

My blog modal Component looks like this.

```
class BlogModal extends React.Component {
  ...
  componentWillMount() {
    if(selectedBlogId){ // call ajax for blog using blog id and set blog form data }
  }

  render() {
    const isEditing = this.props.selectedBlogId !== undefined
    return (
      ....
      {isEditing ? (
          <button type="button" onClick={this.editSelectedBlog}>Update</button>
        ) : (
          <button type="button" onClick={this.addNewBlog}>Save</button>
        )
      }
    )
  }

BlogModal.defaultProps = {
  blog: {
    title: '',
    date: '',
    content: ''
  }
}
```

Is this way of hiding modal and then calling ajax in `componentWillMount` method is recommended or should I remove the `modalShown` condition and always keep the modal and then handle ajax request for editing in `componentWillRecieveProps` method of `BlogModal`?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should do your ajax call in `componentDidMount()` instead.

The [React docs suggest](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount) that this is a better place to perform network requests/side effects rather than `componentWillMount()`.

Secondly, I think that the way you have your logic sprinkled in both the Dashboard and the BlogModal isn't ideal. Instead, I would move the fetching blog data out of the BlogModal and put it in the Dashboard. This way, your BlogModal is only concerned about "presenting" the UI. This is a concept commonly referred to as containers and presentational components or smart and dumb components. Dan Abramov has [a good article](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.1k4schs31) about this concept.

Comment: Thanks. Also, I have Save and Update buttons in the modal which are used for creating a new blog or update an existing blog respectively. Should I also move Post/Put Ajax in the parent method as well? I think these two methods should be part of modal, let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: In that case I would probably make Dashboard only responsible for showing / hiding the BlogModal. Then move all the logic in to BlogModal. Then create seperate components for rendering the buttons - e.g. BlogModalActions - and the content / form - e.g. BlogModalForm. 

BlogModal then is responsible for all the handlers and async and it's children receive callbacks as props to call. i.e. they are presentational.